# Why am I getting a "IndexError: list index out of range" error in my CS50AI Minesweeper code?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, cs50, minesweeper

I'm stuck on my CS50AI Minesweeper project, everything runs fine, but somehow after 10 or 15 movements made by the AI, the program crashes and give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\2-Knowledge\minesweeper\runner.py", line 215, in <module>
    if game.is_mine(move):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\2-Knowledge\minesweeper\minesweeper.py", line 53, in is_mine
    return self.board[i][j]
           ~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my minesweeper.py code (line 53 is highlighted):

```
import itertools
import random


class Minesweeper():
    """
    Minesweeper game representation
    """

    def __init__(self, height=8, width=8, mines=8):

        # Set initial width, height, and number of mines
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.mines = set()

        # Initialize an empty field with no mines
        self.board = []
        for i in range(self.height):
            row = []
            for j in range(self.width):
                row.append(False)
            self.board.append(row)

        # Add mines randomly
        while len(self.mines) != mines:
            i = random.randrange(height)
            j = random.randrange(width)
            if not self.board[i][j]:
                self.mines.add((i, j))
                self.board[i][j] = True

        # At first, player has found no mines
        self.mines_found = set()

    def print(self):
        """
        Prints a text-based representation
        of where mines are located.
        """
        for i in range(self.height):
            print("--" * self.width + "-")
            for j in range(self.width):
                if self.board[i][j]:
                    print("|X", end="")
                else:
                    print("| ", end="")
            print("|")
        print("--" * self.width + "-")

    def is_mine(self, cell):
        i, j = cell
       ** return self.board[i][j] # THIS IS LINE 53**

    def nearby_mines(self, cell):
        """
        Returns the number of mines that are
        within one row and column of a given cell,
        not including the cell itself.
        """

        # Keep count of nearby mines
        count = 0

        # Loop over all cells within one row and column
        for i in range(cell[0] - 1, cell[0] + 2):
            for j in range(cell[1] - 1, cell[1] + 2):

                # Ignore the cell itself
                if (i, j) == cell:
                    continue

                # Update count if cell in bounds and is mine
                if 0 <= i < self.height and 0 <= j < self.width:
                    if self.board[i][j]:
                        count += 1

        return count

    def won(self):
        """
        Checks if all mines have been flagged.
        """
        return self.mines_found == self.mines


class Sentence():
    """
    Logical statement about a Minesweeper game
    A sentence consists of a set of board cells,
    and a count of the number of those cells which are mines.
    """

    def __init__(self, cells, count):
        self.cells = set(cells)
        self.count = count

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.cells == other.cells and self.count == other.count

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.cells} = {self.count}"

    def known_mines(self):
        """
        Returns the set of all cells in self.cells known to be mines.
        """
        if len(self.cells) == self.count and self.count != 0:
            return self.cells
        
        else:
            return set()

    def known_safes(self):
        """
        Returns the set of all cells in self.cells known to be safe.
        """
        if self.count == 0:
            return self.cells
        
        else:
            return set()

    def mark_mine(self, cell):
        """
        Updates internal knowledge representation given the fact that
        a cell is known to be a mine.
        """
        if cell in self.cells:
            self.cells.remove(cell)
            self.count -= 1

    def mark_safe(self, cell):
        """
        Updates internal knowledge representation given the fact that
        a cell is known to be safe.
        """
        if cell in self.cells:
            self.cells.remove(cell)

class MinesweeperAI():
    """
    Minesweeper game player
    """

    def __init__(self, height=8, width=8):

        # Set initial height and width
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

        # Keep track of which cells have been clicked on
        self.moves_made = set()

        # Keep track of cells known to be safe or mines
        self.mines = set()
        self.safes = set()

        # List of sentences about the game known to be true
        self.knowledge = []

    def mark_mine(self, cell):
        """
        Marks a cell as a mine, and updates all knowledge
        to mark that cell as a mine as well.
        """
        self.mines.add(cell)
        for sentence in self.knowledge:
            sentence.mark_mine(cell)

    def mark_safe(self, cell):
        """
        Marks a cell as safe, and updates all knowledge
        to mark that cell as safe as well.
        """
        self.safes.add(cell)
        for sentence in self.knowledge:
            sentence.mark_safe(cell)

    def add_knowledge(self, cell, count):
        """
        Called when the Minesweeper board tells us, for a given
        safe cell, how many neighboring cells have mines in them.

        This function should:
        """
# 1) mark the cell as a move that has been made
        self.moves_made.add(cell)
        
# 2) mark the cell as safe
        self.mark_safe(cell)
        
# 3) add a new sentence to the AI's knowledge base based 
# on the value of `cell` and `count`
        up = cell[1] - 1
        down = cell[1] + 1
        left = cell[0] - 1
        right = cell[0] + 1
        
        undetermined = set()
        mine_counter = 0
        horizontal_boundary = self.width
        vertical_boundary = self.height
        
        for i in range(left, right + 1):
            for j in range(up, down + 1):
                # Ignore i,j if they are out of boundaries or if is the cell itself
                if j < 0 or j > vertical_boundary or i < 0 or i > horizontal_boundary or (i,j) == cell:
                    continue
                
                # Augment mine counter if cell is in mines list
                if (i,j) in self.mines:
                    mine_counter += 1
                
                # Add the cell to the undetermined list if cell is not in safes    
                elif (i,j) not in self.safes:    
                    undetermined.add((i,j))
                print(i,j)
        
        # Add new sentence to KB
        new_counter = count - mine_counter
        new_sentence = Sentence(undetermined, new_counter)
        print(f'Move on cell: {cell} has added sentence to knowledge {undetermined} = {new_counter}' )
        self.knowledge.append(new_sentence)
                        
# 4) mark any additional cells as safe or as mines if it 
# can be concluded based on the AI's knowledge base
        modified = True
        while modified:
            modified = False
            safes = set()
            mines = set()

            for sentence in self.knowledge:
                safes = safes.union(sentence.known_safes())
                mines = mines.union(sentence.known_mines())

            # Mark if cell is safe or mine:
            if safes:
                knowledge_changed = True
                for safe in safes:
                    self.mark_safe(safe)
            if mines:
                knowledge_changed = True
                for mine in mines:
                    self.mark_mine(mine)

            # Update KB removing empty sentences:
            empty = Sentence(set(), 0)

            new_knowledge = []
            for x in self.knowledge:
                if x != empty:
                    new_knowledge.append(x)
            self.knowledge = new_knowledge
            # self.knowledge[:] = [x for x in self.knowledge if x != empty]

#5) add any new sentences to the AI's knowledge base if they can 
# be inferred from existing knowledge
            for sentence_1 in self.knowledge:
                for sentence_2 in self.knowledge:

                    # Ignore when sentences are identical
                    if sentence_1.cells == sentence_2.cells:
                        continue

                    if sentence_1.cells == set() and sentence_1.count > 0:
                        print('Error - sentence with no cells and count created')
                        raise ValueError

                    # Create a new sentence if 1 is subset of 2, and not in KB:
                    if sentence_1.cells.issubset(sentence_2.cells):
                        new_sentence_cells = sentence_2.cells - sentence_1.cells
                        new_sentence_count = sentence_2.count - sentence_1.count

                        new_sentence = Sentence(new_sentence_cells, new_sentence_count)

                        # Add to knowledge if not already in KB:
                        if new_sentence not in self.knowledge:
                            knowledge_changed = True
                            print('New Inferred Knowledge: ', new_sentence, 'from', sentence_1, ' and ', sentence_2)
                            self.knowledge.append(new_sentence)

        # Print out AI current knowledge to terminal:
        print('Current AI KB length: ', len(self.knowledge))
        print('Known Mines: ', self.mines)
        print('Safe Moves Remaining: ', self.safes - self.moves_made)
        print('====================================================')


    def make_safe_move(self):
        """
        Returns a safe cell to choose on the Minesweeper board.
        The move must be known to be safe, and not already a move
        that has been made.

        This function may use the knowledge in self.mines, self.safes
        and self.moves_made, but should not modify any of those values.
        """
        safe_moves = self.safes - self.moves_made
        if safe_moves:
            print('Making a Safe Move! Safe moves available: ', len(safe_moves))
            return random.choice(list(safe_moves))

        # Otherwise no guaranteed safe moves can be made
        return None


    def make_random_move(self):
        """
        Returns a move to make on the Minesweeper board.
        Should choose randomly among cells that:
            1) have not already been chosen, and
            2) are not known to be mines
        """
        for i in range(self.height):
            for j in range(self.width):
                move = (i, j)
                if move not in self.moves_made and move not in self.mines:
                    return move
        return None
```

If someone could help me to know what part of the code is incorrect, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: These types of errors are most easy to debug. Have you used a debugger and stepped through the code, setting break points, inspecting variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example where the last line number in the traceback is **NOT** where the error occurs (e.g. the error is NOT really in the `.is_mine()` method from the Minesweeper class). That method simply returns the board value at the index (either True or False, where True means there is a mine in the cell). The error tells you that you provided invalid `(i,j)` values for the board (either negative or `i>height` or `j>width`).

That method is called from `runner.py` with the `move` value returned by an earlier call to a MinesweeperAI method (either `make_safe_move()` on line 186 or `make_random_move()` on line 188). So, 1 or both of those functions is returning invalid values. Inspect the returned value of `move` (either with the debugger or by adding print statements). Then work backwards to find the source of the error.